# React страница лагает в момент встраивание канвас компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Есть реакт приложение с анимациями, сделанными на framer-motion. Так же есть канвас, в который я импортирую 3д модель с помощью gltfjsx. Проблема заключается  в том, что при загрузки страницы, во время встраивания или после встраивания происходит лаг всей страницы, на момент загрузки этого компонента с канвасом. Все бы ничего, но этот лаг сильно мешает моим анимациям и режет глаз.

Сейчас решил эту проблему костылем - по двух-секундному таймауту (как раз за это время все анимации проигрываются) вызываю этот компонент, но такая реализация не дает мне спокойно жить и хочется решить эту проблему так, как она должна быть решена.

Ниже приложу ссылку на проект на гите. Страница home. Компонент с канвасом IphoneComponent
https://github.com/sparkkkd/Apple-shop/